# How to make this spring-boot code work on weblogic 10.3.6?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, weblogic-10.x, spring-oauth2

I am using spring boot 1.5.0 with Java 7 and trying to deploy my code on weblogic 10.3.6 but I am unable to deploy it and giving some errors. I am also using oauth2 for authentication

my classes :

**1) UserController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/all")
    public WebAPIResponse<User> getAll(){
        System.out.println("inside user all");
        LOGGER.info("inside /user/all endpoint");
        return userService.getAll();
    }
}
```

**2) UserRepository.java**

```
@Repository(value = "userRepo")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {

}
```

**3) UserRepositoryCustom.java**

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {

    User getByUsername(String username) throws Exception;
}
```

**4) UserRepositoryCustomImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryCustomImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public User getByUsername(String username) throws Exception {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username = :username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

**5) UserService.java**

```
public interface UserService {
    WebAPIResponse<User> getByUsername(String username);
}
```

skipping implementation of UserService here

**OAuth Classes:**

1) AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static String REALM="MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        int accessTokenMinutesValidity = 60;
        int refreshTokenMinutesValidity = 24 * 60;
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials","password", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * accessTokenMinutesValidity ).//Access token is only valid for 60 minutes.
            refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60 * refreshTokenMinutesValidity);//Refresh token is only valid for 24 hours
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
            .realm(REALM+"/client");
    }

}
```

**2) MethodSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

**3) OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource customDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        //datasource settings here

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource ds() {
        //return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        return customDataSource();
    }


    //USERS FROM DATABASE
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        BCryptPasswordEncoder enc;

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select USERNAME, ENC_PASSWD as PASSWORD, IS_ACTIVE AS ENABLED FROM USER_MSTR WHERE USERNAME=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select USERNAME, 'ROLE_CLIENT' as ROLE from USER_MSTR where USERNAME=?")
        .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
        ;

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore){
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

}
```

**4) ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "my_rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
        anonymous().disable()
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/category_mstr/**", "/equipment/**", "/param_mstr/**", "/chklist_txn/**", "/settings/**", "/user/**")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/category_mstr/**", "/equipment/**", "/param_mstr/**", "/chklist_txn/**", "/settings/**", "/user/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

Also attaching my  config files here :

1) weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <wls:context-root>IndogulfAPI</wls:context-root>
      <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:container-descriptor>  
<wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>

    </wls:container-descriptor>


</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

**2) web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.grasim.IndogulfAPI.IndogulfApiApplication</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**EDIT -----**

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.grasim</groupId>
    <artifactId>IndogulfAPI</artifactId>
<!--    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>IndogulfAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.12.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> -->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

          <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
          <!-- c#11 -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

                <!-- Spring Security -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security OAuth2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurityoauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>   
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you please commit your project to GitHub and provide a link, this will be easy to other developers to debug.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati ok

Answer (score 0):

why do you have web.xml in spring-boot application, and you should use just spring not spring boot if you want to deploy in weblogic container, also can you please add your pom.xml or gradle file as well.

Comment: I have attached pom.xml in edit. I had to add web.xml because some of the other answers suggested it for compatibility with servlet 2.5